# Anyone know the soap calls needed to create an order

Tags: orders, soap

I'm trying to insert an order via the soap calls.  I can't figure out what calls would be needed to create and tie off an order, start to finish.

I'm not doing this in php, but if I have all the calls listed in the wsdl, then I could figure out what they're really called..

I just really need the names of the standard calls.

Comment: What did you try? What calls did you made and what is your exact problem? The wsdl can be found here:
http://demo.magentocommerce.com/api/?wsdl

Comment: I am not in the try phase.  I can easily call all the soap I just need to know what the calls are :)  Thanks for helping with the WSDL.. it's slightly different than the one I'm targeting, but nice to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have a php example (from the [Magento API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cart/cart.order.html) manual) on how to create an order with the needed calls:

```
/**
 * Example of order creation
 * Preconditionsare as follows:
 * 1. Create a customer
 * 2. Сreate a simple product */

$user = 'apiUser';
$password = 'apiKey';
    $proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
    $sessionId = $proxy->login($user, $password);
    $cartId = $proxy->shoppingCartCreate($sessionId, 1);
    // load the customer list and select the first customer from the list
    $customerList = $proxy->customerCustomerList($sessionId, array());
    $customer = (array) $customerList[0];
    $customer['mode'] = 'customer';
    $proxy->shoppingCartCustomerSet($sessionId, $cartId, $customer);
    // load the product list and select the first product from the list
    $productList = $proxy->catalogProductList($sessionId);
    $product = (array) $productList[0];
    $product['qty'] = 1;
    $proxy->shoppingCartProductAdd($sessionId, $cartId, array($product));

    $address = array(
        array(
            'mode' => 'shipping',
            'firstname' => $customer['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $customer['lastname'],
            'street' => 'street address',
            'city' => 'city',
            'region' => 'region',
            'telephone' => 'phone number',
            'postcode' => 'postcode',
            'country_id' => 'country ID',
            'is_default_shipping' => 0,
            'is_default_billing' => 0
        ),
        array(
            'mode' => 'billing',
            'firstname' => $customer['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $customer['lastname'],
            'street' => 'street address',
            'city' => 'city',
            'region' => 'region',
            'telephone' => 'phone number',
            'postcode' => 'postcode',
            'country_id' => 'country ID',
            'is_default_shipping' => 0,
            'is_default_billing' => 0
        ),
    );
     // add customer address
    $proxy->shoppingCartCustomerAddresses($sessionId, $cartId, $address);
    // add shipping method
    $proxy->shoppingCartShippingMethod($sessionId, $cartId, 'flatrate_flatrate');

    $paymentMethod =  array(
        'po_number' => null,
        'method' => 'checkmo',
        'cc_cid' => null,
        'cc_owner' => null,
        'cc_number' => null,
        'cc_type' => null,
        'cc_exp_year' => null,
        'cc_exp_month' => null
    );
     // add payment method
    $proxy->shoppingCartPaymentMethod($sessionId, $cartId, $paymentMethod);
     // place the order
    $orderId = $proxy->shoppingCartOrder($sessionId, $cartId, null, null);
```

Comment: Wow... thanks!  Php is a little hard, but I can suss out the calls.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution
Create appropriate role (Magento Admin)
Create web services user (Magento Admin)
Assign created role to the user (Magento Admin)
Log-in to web service and retrieve Session Id (Soap Client)
Call appropriate method (Soap Client)

here is the link for magento api uses
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html